# How to implement custom icon in SAPUI5's Shellbar Control?

Tags: sapui5

I implemented a functionality so that the users of my SAPUI5 application can change between different SAPUI5 themes. Now I would like to place a button in the existing `ShellBar` of my app to trigger that functionality from there.

Currently I have a fragment with the following code, which I want to make use of within a simple button in the `ShellBar`. I tried different things like f.ex. calling it via the `avaterPressed` attribute from the shellbar, but it looks all messed up - I'd be very happy if someone could help me out here - Thanks!

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
            <Menu itemSelected="onSelectTheme" >
                <MenuItem text="Choose Theme">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem key="sap_fiori_3" text="Standard Light" />
                        <MenuItem key="sap_fiori_3_dark" text="Standard Dark" />
                        <MenuItem key="sap_hcw" text="High Contrast White" />
                        <MenuItem key="sap_hcb" text="High Contrast Black" />
                    </items>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

It should look like the "Administrator" button in the following example (Instead of "User Settings" there should be my text "Choose Theme" from the fragment shown above: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/tnt/demokit/toolpageapp/webapp/index.html?sap-ui-theme=sap_horizon#/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developers from the linked example don't use the SAPUI5 Control `ShellBar`, but instead they made use of `ToolHeader`, which you can also implement within the Control `ToolPage`.

With `ToolHeader`, you can simply add a `Button` wherever you'd like and also call the fragment from f.ex. the profile picture button (shown below).

```
<tnt:ToolHeader>
  <Avatar src="..." press="YOUR_FUNCTION_TO_OPEN_FRAGMENT"/>
</tnt:ToolHeader>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using the ShellBar, you can implement the press event on the Avatar and use the ActionSheet for your needs.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.ActionSheet/sample/sap.m.sample.ActionSheet